# Not working sending email with python

Tags: python, email

I run this code, but nothing happens and it gives me syntax error.

```
import smtplib

content = 'example sk'

mail = smtplib.SMTP ('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

mail.ehlo ()

mail.startttls ()

mail.login('example@gmail.com,'example')

mail.sendmail ('example@gmail.com', 'example1@gmail.com', 'hi')

mail.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is here:

`mail.login('example@gmail.com,'example')`

it should be:

```
mail.login('example@gmail.com', 'example')
-----------------------------^
```

For future questions, please include the full error traceback in your question.

Comment: please refrain to answer such stupid questions. The syntax error can be seen in the code view of the question (different color). A comment would have been ehough

Comment: @mpf82 hello man. Do u know by any chance how can i import list of 500 emails from my excel file into python and send massive email? Thanks a lot, man! Sadly, i can't give reputation yet, it requires me to have 15 posts or something